# get-запрос с параметрами для авторизации

Tags: yii2, get, авторизация

Нужно с одного сайта перейти по нажатию ссылки на другой, так что бы в `get` параметрах передать данные (логин, пароль авторизованного пользователя) и по этим данным авторизоваться на том сайте куда перешел.
Сайт работает на Yii2

Comment: В гет-запросе нельзя передавать такие данные. Можно шифровать айди пользователя и генерировать ключ (со временем жизни), передавать на другой сайт и там дешифровать, авторизовывать. Алгоритм шифрования должен быть одинаковый и ключ.

Comment: спасибо большое)